# I want to split a XML Like string to tokens in c# or sql

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xml-parsing

I want to split a XML Like string to tokens in c# or sql.
for example 
input string is like

```
<entry><AUTHOR>C. Qiao</AUTHOR> and <AUTHOR>R.Melhem</AUTHOR>, "<TITLE>Reducing Communication </TITLE>",<DATE>1995</DATE>. </entry>
```

and I want this output:

```
C       AUTHOR
.       AUTHOR
Qiao    AUTHOR
and 
R       AUTHOR
.       AUTHOR
Melhem  AUTHOR
,   
"
Reducing        TITLE
Communication   TITLE
"
,
1995    DATE
.
```

Comment: This doesn't look like well-formatted XML ! Isn't it? And what have you done so far? Please share so that people can help to improve

Comment: i have a lot of data like this i want to train from this data with hmm and predict new reference part and tag in unseen reference

Comment: Since the question has nothing to do with sql or sql server please consider removing the tags- they are misleading, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first attempt on how to solve this problem, considering the following:
1. XML String will be valid (i.e. there's not going to be any invalid chars between tags)
Like this:

```
string xml = @"<ENTRY><AUTHOR>C. Qiao</AUTHOR>
                                  <AUTHOR>R.Melhem</AUTHOR>
                                  <TITLE>Reducing Communication </TITLE>
                                  <DATE>1995</DATE>
                           </ENTRY>";
```

2. Splitting will be done by space `' '`

```
string xml = @"<ENTRY><AUTHOR>C. Qiao</AUTHOR>
                              <AUTHOR>R.Melhem</AUTHOR>
                              <TITLE>Reducing Communication </TITLE>
                              <DATE>1995</DATE>
                       </ENTRY>";
        XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Elements())
        {

            var values = element.Value.Split(' ');
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Name + " " + value);
            }
        }
```

Will print out

```
AUTHOR C.
AUTHOR Qiao
AUTHOR R.Melhem
TITLE Reducing
TITLE Communication
TITLE
DATE 1995
```

**EDIT:**

Now, to split based on "." and a space, the best idea is to use regex. Like this:

```
   var values = Regex.Split(element.Value, @"(\.| )");
        foreach (string value in values.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Name + " " + value);
        }
```

You can add more delimiters if you'd like. The following example will give you the following:

```
AUTHOR C
AUTHOR .
AUTHOR Qiao
AUTHOR R
AUTHOR .
AUTHOR Melhem
TITLE Reducing
TITLE Communication
DATE 1995
```

**Edit2:**
And here's an example that works with your original string, it is most likely not the best approach, since it doesn't have a correct ordering of tokens, but it should be pretty close:

```
 string xml = @" <entry>
                            <AUTHOR>C. Qiao</AUTHOR> 
                            and 
                            <AUTHOR>R.Melhem</AUTHOR>, 
                            ""<TITLE>Reducing Communication </TITLE>""
                           ,<DATE>1995</DATE>. 
                           </entry>";
            //Parse xml to XDocument
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            // Get first element (we only have one)
            XElement element = doc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault();

            //Create a copy of an element for use by child elements.
            XElement copyElement = new XElement(element);
            //Remove all child nodes from root leaving only text
            element.Elements().Remove();

            //Splitting based on the tokens specified
                var values = Regex.Split(element.Value, @"(\.| |\,|\"")");
                    foreach (string value in values.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
                    }
            //Getting children nodes and splitting the same way
            foreach (XElement elem in copyElement.Elements())
            {
                var val = Regex.Split(elem.Value, @"(\.| |\,|\"")");
                foreach (string value in val.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value + " " + elem.Name);
                }
            }
            //You can try to play with DescendantsAndSelf 
            //to see if you can do it in single action and with order preserved.
            //foreach (XElement elem in element.DescendantsAndSelf())
            //{
            //    //....
            //}
```

This will print out the following:

```
and
,
"
"
,
.
C AUTHOR
. AUTHOR
Qiao AUTHOR
R AUTHOR
. AUTHOR
Melhem AUTHOR
Reducing TITLE
Communication TITLE
1995 DATE
```

Comment: The XML provided in the questions is valid XML. The `entry` node is a mixed content node with both elements and text.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, thanks for pointing that out, you're correct. I've added some code that deals with the original string.

Comment: @user1792936 tanks for your answer but i need real order in output like in sample in question

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just noticed I read the question wrong - having copied the formatted XML from the first answer instead of from the question I failed to notice the mixed content nodes within the string. This makes it easier. The solution could look like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = @"<entry><AUTHOR>C. Qiao</AUTHOR> and <AUTHOR>R.Melhem</AUTHOR>, ""<TITLE>Reducing Communication </TITLE>"",<DATE>1995</DATE>. </entry>";

        var elem = XElement.Parse(xml);

        var tokFunc = new Func<XNode, string>(node =>
            {
                var s = node.ToString().Replace(".", " . ").Replace(",", " , ");
                var nodeName = node.Parent != null && 
                    node.Parent.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && 
                    node.Parent.Name.LocalName.ToUpper() != "ENTRY"
                                   ? node.Parent.Name.LocalName
                                   : "";
                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                s.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(e => sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\n", e, nodeName));
                return sb.ToString();
            });


        elem.DescendantNodes().Where(e => e.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).ToList()
            .ForEach(c => Console.Write(tokFunc(c)));


    }
}
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
C       AUTHOR
.       AUTHOR
Qiao    AUTHOR
and
R       AUTHOR
.       AUTHOR
Melhem  AUTHOR
,
"
Reducing        TITLE
Communication   TITLE
"
,
1995    DATE
.
```